# Which Crawled property to map in managed property for 'Title' from a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, managed-property, refiner, crawled-property

I am working on Creating a custom search result page with **custom refiners**. And I am stuck with choosing the appropriate crawled property to map to Refinable string managed property. Do someone knows the exact applicable crawled property for a '**Title**' field from a **document library.**

I have already tried with *OWS_Title, Title, OWS_LinkTitle*. But no luck!

**Edit1:**

[image]

TIA

Comment: Have you run full crawl after you created new mapping?

Comment: I am on SP Online so I can not run a full crawl.. But I can wait till full crawl though

Comment: We only started moving to SP online so my experience in this area is still limited, but on prem the mappings only work after full crawl so most probably you need to wait.

Comment: Hi DvG, I am having the same issue - I have mapped crawl property ows_Title to Managed Property RefinableString00, but am not able to sort on it, despite forcing a crawl by re-indexing the site. In your answer below on 22nd June 2018 you state: " Eventually, I ended up for doing Keyward search as Title: <search-keyward>. This has shown the relevant result ". Could you expand on this as I am not sure where I would do this keyword search within the PnP Search Results web part.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the out of the box Title managed property? It is mapped to:

- Title
- MetadataExtractorTitle
- TermTitle
- Office:2
- ows_BaseName
- MailSubjec
- Mail:5
- People:PreferredName
- Basic:displaytitle
- ows_Title
- Basic:10
- Basic:9

I should point out that Title is generally a poor choice for refinement as the values are often unique. Refinement works best when a group of documents share that attribute.

Comment: Thanku for the reply, I actually need Title field as refiner because there is another field RecordNumber which is unique in my case..And these fields are from document library. So out of these list which one will suit for my case. ?

Comment: If it's the title field from a Document Library, use ows_Title. For RecordNumber use ows_RecordNumber.

Comment: As per my question description, I have already used ows_title as crawled property.. and now i m awaiting for full crwal to happen. Then I can b confirmed.. FYI: i am on SP online

Comment: I have tried with TermTitle, MetadataExtractorTitle, Basic:displaytitle, Title, ows_Title, TermTitle, Title and ows_LinkTitle as refinable string001,2,3,4,5,6 but none of them worked even after full crawl.. Eventually, I ended up for doing Keyward search as Title: <search-keyward>. This has shown the relevant result

Comment: So, it's working for you?

Comment: Yes Matthew, only if I am using ‘Title’ as KQL query. I was a trying the refinableString way so that I can alias this as ‘DocumetTitle’

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit more research in that area and yes the crawl needs to happen. There seems to be a way (Haven't tested it) to force it by setting the property bag ("vti_searchversion") on sites. More info here: http://makingthings.work/trigger-a-full-crawl-on-sharepoint-online/

Comment: pls see my last comment on Matthew's answer